# Restkit request.body values between square brackets

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm doing a very basic POST request.
setting my `requestSerializationMIMEType` into `RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded` as my server would expect (although it's the default).

Now in the log the `request.body` would look like this:

```
request.body=[param1]=test&[param2]=2724
```

Resulting unknown form values in the server.

The problem here is the param names, they're between square brackets, which I don't have an explanation why they're serialised like this!

My code is somehow exactly the same of the example provided on [github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-patch-and-delete-an-object).

NOTE: I have done the POST request manually without the square brackets and it's working fine.

**EDIT**

The code

```
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GenericResponse class]];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"error":@"error", @"status":@"status"}];
NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); 
RKResponseDescriptor *genericDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];

RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; 
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[User generateJSONMapping]];//dictionary mapping
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://foo.com/rest/createUser/"]];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:genericDescriptor];
manager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;

// POST to create
[manager postObject:user path:@"" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"success");// the request is success but the params are not delivered to the server 
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}];
```

The `User` is very simple I guess

```
@interface User : NSObject
   @property NSNumber *idShort;
   @property NSNumber *idLong;
   @property NSNumber *idCom;
   @property NSString *comment;
   @property NSString *token;

   + (NSDictionary *) generateJSONMapping;
@end


@implementation User
   + (NSDictionary *) generateJSONMapping
   {
      return @{
         @"idShort": @"idShort",
         @"idLong": @"idLong",
         @"idCom":@"idCom",
         @"comment":@"comment",
         @"token":@"token",
         };
   }
@end
```

Comment: Please post the code that creates the body.

Comment: Can you also show `generateJSONMapping` and the `User` class (property definitions).

Comment: I have updated the question.
btw my class is not called User, but the properties are the same (I used User just to demonstrate) @Wain

Comment: And they all come out in brackets? I can't see an obvious reason why...

Comment: Yes the names are always between brackets! me too, although I don't have that big experience with that API, but my code seems fine! can I write some custom serializer maybe?   @Wain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `RKRequestDescriptor`, passing `rootKeyPath` as an empty string would cause this.
Passing `nil` would solve the problem.

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [
RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
objectClass:[User class]
rootKeyPath:nil
method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```